# Put a DropDownList instead of TextBox in DetailsView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an EntityDataSource control that is bind to an edmx file.
I create a detailsview and set it's DataSource property to entitydatasource control.

[image]

now I want to put a DropDownList instead of TextBox for "no_region_code" in Inserting mode.
Here is what I found from internet but it does not insert the contents of dropdownlist to the table when i click on insert button of detailsview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="no_region_code" SortExpression="no_region_code">

                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_region_list" runat="server" DataMember="no_region_code">
        <asp:ListItem Value="41">tabriz</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="21">tehran</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I put a dropdownlist instead of these textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't bind any property on that `DropDownList`. Try something like this

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_region_list" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("no_region_code")%>' DataMember="no_region_code">
        <asp:ListItem Value="41">tabriz</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="21">tehran</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

**EDIT** : bind represent a way to link your property from the code behind (or model) to an asp control. This binding is bidirectional. For example, if you already have a value for `no_region_code` property in the code behind, the dropdown will already have that value selected on the view. Google asp.net data binding and you'll find a lot of examples and some more in depth explanations.